# Jquery: Give styling (padding) of the parent class based on the condition that the first child matches with the class I want

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-objects

Parent Class: cmp-container
There are two child classes -
productmodelfootnotes
footnotes

According to the sequence of the child I want to give padding as follows -
If "productmodelfootnotes" child class comes first -> Apply padding=40px to the parent class (cmp-container)
If "footnotes" child class comes first -> Apply padding=64px to the parent class (cmp-container)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, initialize your parent element

```
let parent = document.querySelector('.cmp-container')
```

Then add style, based on condition

```
let firstChild = parent.children[0];
if(firstChild.classlist.contains('productmodelfootnotes'){
    parent.style.padding = "40px";
} else if(firstChild.classlist.contains('footnotes')) {
    parent.style.padding = "64px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".cmp-container").each(function(i, el) {
    if ($("div:eq(0)", el).hasClass("productmodelfootnotes")) {
      $(el).addClass("shortpad");
    } else if ($("div:eq(0)", el).hasClass("footnotes")) {
      $(el).addClass("longpad");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.cmp-container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.cmp-container .footnotes {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.cmp-container .productmodelfootnotes {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.shortpad {
  padding: 40px;
}

.longpad {
  padding: 64px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cmp-container">
  <div class="productmodelfootnotes">
    Product Note 1
  </div>
  <div class="footnotes">
    Foot Note 1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cmp-container">
  <div class="footnotes">
    Foot Note 2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cmp-container">
  <div class="productmodelfootnotes">
    Product Note 3
  </div>
  <div class="footnotes">
    Foot Note 3
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cmp-container">
  <div class="footnotes">
    Foot Note 4
  </div>
  <div class="productmodelfootnotes">
    Product Note 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Using `.each()`, we can iterate over the DIV elements and check the order of the children. If they meet the specific condition, we can add a Class or apply a Style to that element.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/each/

I assign `i` as the Index and `el` as the Element. I then use a Find selector, `$("div:eq(0)", el)` which is the same as `$(el).find("div").eq(0)` where `0` represents the first item in the list or elements that is Found.

Using `.hasClass()` we can check if it is `true` or `false`, and perform a specific action based on the condition.

See More: https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

I used an `if` / `else if` statement to check two conditions. This is in case another element may appear first that should not have any padding.